# Sharing state between two reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two reducers, the first one fetches data and the second one is used to filter the data based on changes to the original data. I have read that using `combineReducers` is not an option.

**My postReducer**

```
import {FETCH_POST} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_POST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: action.payload});
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**My pinReducer**

```
import {PIN_POST} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case PIN_POST:
            console.log(state.items);
            const item = state.items.map(value => value.data.id === action.id ?
                {data: Object.assign({}, value.data, {pinned: action.val})} : value
            );
            //console.log(item);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: item });
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import postReducer from './postReducer';
import pinReducer from './pinReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    post: postReducer,
    pin: pinReducer
});
```

How can I share the state between the two reducers, as `state.items` in the pinReducer is empty

Comment: There's a bunch of posts about this, even a page in the official Redux documentation about it. Basically, you shouldn't be sharing state between reducers. In your case, I see no reason why you separated it into 2 separate reducers, they have exactly the same properties. You can handle both actions (and other actions relating to the `items`) in the same reducer.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to "share", then those reducers are processing the same state, then you have to merge them into one reducer only. Because each reducer are mapping to a different slice of state, so the actions that modify the SAME state definitely go into the same reducer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a reducers that has state derived on the basis of other reducers. What you need in your case is a selector(more efficiently a memoizedSelector), for which you can use `reselect` library

**My postReducer**

```
import {FETCH_POST} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_POST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: action.payload});
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import postReducer from './postReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    post: postReducer,
});
```

and then where you want to use pinItem, you can do that in mapStateToProps

```
getPinItem = (state, props) => {
    const item = state.items.map(value => value.data.id === action.id ?
                {data: Object.assign({}, value.data, {pinned: action.val})} : value
    );
    return item;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    const pinItem = getPinItem(state, props);
    return {
        pinItem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reducer does not access to store's state, nor other reducers' previous state. Only to its own previous state and dispatched action. You can think of it as a single brick in the wall of redux' state.

In your case, we have to tackle the logic and decide what is an actual state here.

**Requirements:**

1. fetch a list of posts: state is an array of posts;
2. pin one of these posts: state is an id of currently pinned post;
3. get currently pinned post: find a post in an array by pinned post id.

**Solution:**

1 - initial posts reducer:

```
const initialState = { items: [] }

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return { items: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

2 - add info about pinned post:

```
const initialState = { items: [], pinnedId: null }

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return { ...state, items: action.payload.posts }
    case PIN_POST:
      return { ...state, pinnedId: action.payload.id }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

3 - get a currently pinned post:

```
// assuming that store is configured...
export default combineReducers({ posts: postsReducer })
// ...

// somewhere in `connect`
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    pinnedPost: state.posts.find(post => post.id === state.posts.pinnedId),
  }
}
```

So now we store a minimum information about a pinned post (only its id) and it is enough to get an actual pinned post.

Also, as mentioned in another answer by @shubham-khatri, you can use optimized selectors. With current shape of the state storing pinned id separately, it is even more efficient since your selector will depend on two inputs: posts array (is re-created on fetch, so shallow comparable) and pinned id (is a primitive number or string, also easy to compare).

I'd encourage you to store as minimum information in store as possible. Also, store it in simple and flat shape. Move everything that's can be calculated to selectors.